openshift db2 ssl remote database
I have a db2 instance in openshift. I can attach to this instance from my laptop with a ssl route.
I have the following issue when I want to create a remote database (from my laptop to openshift).
The database it will be created remotely (it was checked in openshift) but after the operation is finished I have the error:
SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol
being used: "SSL".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where
the error was detected: "".  Communication function detecting the error:
"sqlccSSLSocketRead".  Protocol specific error code(s): "420", "", "".
SQLSTATE=08001
I tried to add different timeout settings like haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout = 120s but the error still appears.
How could I get rid of this error, especially since the database is being created.
I added timeouts in network/route settings in openshift.
I can attach remotely to this instance with the CA certificate.
I can connect to a database, from my laptop, which was created in openshift.

What is the plain text output of the db2level command on your laptop (search for this in the file system on your laptop, and run in a cmd window or terminal window ) .  Also the question is unclear,  exactly which command fails on your laptop?  Is it the create database or a subsequent connect that fails?

db2level shows me that I have db2 11.5.9.

The database is created with success but I have this error at the end.

Troubleshooting required. Verify this only happens after a attach from remote (i.e. eliminate if attach from a local-to-db2server ssh terminal causes the create database to succeed).  Check Db2-server diagnostics file on both the Db2-server and the Db2-client sides for any extra clues why the connection is getting closed (gskit error 420). You might need to open a ticket with IBM. You can also trace (with db2trc ) what is  happening from the client side which may also expose the culprit.
